# Making custom function write data to another cell

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

Currently, I am trying to make custom function to be able to write data to another cell.

Since excel custom function itself does not support writing to another cell, so I am using taskpane to write it instead. I use onCalculated event to trigger taskpane to write to the cell that is specified in the formula.

Example formula:
=test("a", D4) << means that taskpane will write "a" to D4 cell.

After I tried, I am able to write "a" to D4 cell but there is an issue.
So when "a" is written to D4 cell, the formula will recalculate again since it is referencing to that D4 cell. This will cause it to trigger onCalculated event forever.

So what is the best approach to make custom function to be able to write data to another cell?

Comment: Have a look here for tips on suspending calculations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/performance 

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  In a **standard module**:

```
Public addy As String
Public stuff As Variant

Public Function test(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
    test = "done"
    stuff = s1
    addy = s2
End Function
```

[image]

In the **worksheet code area:**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableAnimations = False
        Range(addy) = stuff
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

and in a **worksheet cell**:

```
=test(A1,B1)
```

[image]

**Notes:**

- The UDF does not fill the "extra" cell, the event sub does.

Answer (score 0):

Does =test("a", "D4") work for you?